# Log into Sharepoint 2013 Development installation

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I just installed SharePoint 2013 on a VM. I need to get into Central Admin but it is asking for a username and password. What is it? Or is there a way I can set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your self in Administrator group of the machine. Go to IE > Tools > Internet Options >Security Tab >Trusted Sites > sites > Add central Admin site url & uncheck require server verification > Click on Add > Custom Level > Scroll down to the bottom & select Automatic logon with current username and password and click ok.

Answer (score 0):

The default account that has access initially is the account with which you installed Sharepoint.  Typically, you create a dedicated install account when doing installation, upgrades, patches, etc.  Use this account to log into the central administration site.